# Агрессивные коровы

Tags: алгоритм

Помогите найти оптимальное решение задачи (спортивное программирование):

> ФД построил новый длинный амбар с N (2 <= N <= 100,000) стойлами.
>
> Стойла расположены вдоль прямой линии на позициях x1,...,xN
> (0 <= xi <= 1,000,000,000).
>
> Его C (2 <= C <= N) коровам не нравится такой амбар и они становятся
> агрессивными при установке их в стойла. Чтобы избежать прямых
> столкновений, ФД хочет назначить коровам стойла так, чтобы минимальное
> расстояние между любыми двумя из них было максимальным насколько это
> возможно.
>
> Каково это минимальное расстояние?
>
> Формат ввода:
>
> - Строка 1: Два разделенных пробелом целых числа N и C
> - Строки 2..N+1: Строка i+1 содержит целые числа - места расположения стойл - xi
>
> Пример ввода:
> 5 3
> 1
> 2
> 8
> 4
> 9
>
> OUTPUT FORMAT:
>
> - Строка 1: Одно целое число - максимальное минимальное расстояние
>
> Пример вывода:
> 3
>
> Пояснения к выводу.
>
> ФД может расставить 3 своих коровы в стойла в позициях 1, 4 и 8, в результате чего получиться минимальное расстояние 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ПРИДУМАЛ!
решение за NlogN.

отсортируем все позиции по возрастанию (NlogN - qsort).

затем будем делать дихотомию по ответу (если можно так сказать), т. е. дихотомией перебираем возможный ответ M (за всего log(10^9) ~ 35 шагов) и пробуем расставить максимальное (не из условия а вообще максимальное) количество коров, чтобы расстояние между соседними не превышало M. (за линейное время - количество стойл 10^5). Если расставили больше коров, чем надо, то увеличиваем нижнюю границу дихотомии (ищем расстояние больше), иначе уменьшаем верхнюю(мы не сможем расставить требуемое количество коров следовательно, делаем верхнюю границу приближенного ответа меньше).

@gecube:

> А теперь бы увидеть код и погонять его
> :-)

легко ))) (Простите за pascal, просто мне нравиться решать задачи именно в нём)

```
const
        maxN     = 111111;

var
        i,n,c,j,count,cur               : longint;

        a                               : array [1..maxN] of longint;

        l,r,m                           : longint;

        ans                             : longint;

procedure swap(var w1,w2 : longint);
        var
                temp : longint;
        begin
                temp := w1; w1 := w2; w2 := temp;
        end;

procedure qsort(left,right : longint);
        var
                i,j,key : longint;
        begin
                i := left; j := right;
                key := a[(i + j) shr 1];
                repeat
                        while (a[i] < key) do inc(i);
                        while (a[j] > key) do dec(j);
                        if (i <= j) then begin
                                swap(a[i],a[j]);
                                inc(i); dec(j);
                        end;
                until i>j;
                if (i < right) then qsort(i,right);
                if (j > left)  then qsort(left,j);
        end;

begin
        readln(n,c);
        for i := 1 to n do begin
                read(a[i]);
                if a[i] > r then r := a[i];
        end;

        qsort(1,n);

        while l < r do begin
                m := (l + r + 1) shr 1;

                count := 1;
                cur := a[1];
                for i := 2 to n do
                        if a[i] - cur < m
                                then
                                        continue
                                else begin
                                        cur := a[i];
                                        inc(count);
                                end;

                if count >= c
                        then begin
                                l := m;
                                if count >= c
                                        then
                                                ans := m;
                        end
                        else begin
                                r := m-1;
                        end;
        end;

        writeln(ans);

end.
```

Comment: А теперь бы увидеть код и погонять его :-)

Answer (score 0):

Самое простое: рассмотреть все варианты размещения коров. 
Т.е. для примера с 3 коровами и 5 стойлами:
1 2 8, 1 2 4, 1 2 9, 1 8 4, 1 8 9, 1 4 9, 2 8 4, 2 8 9, 2 4 9, 8 4 9.
Получается всего лишь 10 вариантов (сочетание из 5 по 3 = 5!/(3!*(5-3)!)).
Далее не проблема рассчитать для каждого случая минимальное расстояние между коровами и сохранить его в переменной. Ну, а далее просто ищем сравниваем текущее минимальное расстояние с максимальным найденным.

PS: еще пара прикидок. Первая - минимальное расстояние может быть максимально при максимальной длине отрезка между первой коровой и последней. Т.е. выгодно выбрать два стойла с минимальной абсолютной координатой и с максимальной. Хотя не факт, что это работает всегда. Вторая - наихудший вариант с точки зрения производительности для полного перебора - какое-то среднее кол-во коров (где-то половина от кол-ва стойл). Очевидно, что если кол-во стойл = кол-ву коров, то задача решена сразу :-) И когда 2 коровы, то тоже все ясно. Третья - вероятно имеет смысл отсортировать стойла по возрастанию координат. Также ясно, что может быть вариант, когда два стойла имеют одну и ту же координату. Хотя вряд ли он корректен.

PPS:

> ФД может расставить 3 своих коровы в стойла в позициях 1, 4 и 8, в результате чего получиться минимальное расстояние 3.

При варианте 1,4,9 получаются расстояния 3 и 5, что всяко лучше, чем 3 и 4.

Comment: @gecube
в задаче главное - максимизировать минимальное расстояние. поэтому и в примере из условия и в Вашем примере ответ 3 (одинаковый).

всего коров 100 тысяч, поэтому генерация размещений (как у Вас) и затем определение минимального расстояния, не поможет.(слишком долго)

ps. я не написал комментарий, т. к. мой браузер на мобильнике(opera mini) чего-то дает нажать на 'комментировать'.  разработчики, пересмотрите пожалуйста скрипты, чтобы все работало.

Comment: "поэтому генерация размещений (как у Вас)" - можно соптимизировать. Например, понятно, что если мы нашли вариант с меньшим расстоянием, чем у нас даже между первыми двумя коровами, то можно его пропустить. Т.е. ,например, рассмотрели вариант 2 8 4 (длины - 6 и 4), то далее вариант 2 4 9 полностью обсчитывать не надо, т.к. он уже при первой итерации будет заведомо хуже.

Comment: и какая у Вас тогда будет сложность алгоритма?

на счет примера: в задаче важно не не размещение, а ответ - макс из миним расстояний. а вариантов получения правильного ответа может быть и больше.

Comment: "поэтому и в примере из условия и в Вашем примере ответ 3 (одинаковый)." - вообще-то под условие подпадают оба варианта. Но с точки зрения логики - коровы должны быть максимально далеко, мой вариант лучше. К тому же при определенном решении выпадет именно вариант 1 4 9 с минимальным расстоянием 3.

Comment: Можно оценить верхнюю границу задачи так. У нас C коров и N амбаров. Следовательно, максимальное возможное расстояние между коровами в принципе будет (max(x1,xN)-min(x1,xN))/C. Объясню. Если мы увеличим какое-либо расстояние больше этой величины, то любое уменьшится на эту же величину. Вероятно, это можно использовать. Т.е. чем равномернее распределение - тем ближе к решению задачи. Хм.

Comment: "и какая у Вас тогда будет сложность алгоритма?" - с оптимизациями - существенно ниже. :-) Насколько - сказать сложно. Нужно пробовать.

Comment: "а вариантов получения правильного ответа может быть много." - наверняка, но смотря с какой стороны подходить.

Comment: "я не написал комментарий" - создание комментария требует минимум 50 репутации.

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что это задача на динамическое программирование. Начинаем перебирать возможные ответы, начиная с максимума и в цикле решаем задачи расставить бешеных коров на расстоянии друг от друга не меньше, чем наше фиксированное число. Предположив размещение очередной бешеной коровы, начинаем решать эту же задачу, но с уменьшенной сложностью для оставшихся коров на оставшихся участках. При этом рассматриваем только те варианты, которые потенциально могут привести к решению (а их гораздо меньше, чем полный перебор). Как только коров удалось расставить - ответ готов. Теоретически можно хешировать промежуточные результаты для большей эффективности, но боюсь, это потребует слишком много памяти.

Comment: Действительно, вместо перебора сверху вниз стоит использовать дихотомию.